# Confused about the correctness of small signal models in power electronics

Tags: power-electronics

In power electronics, the most commonly used modeling methods are probably the **state-space averaging modeling** and **averaged switch modeling**.

First we get the large signal model. Then assuming that the disturbance is very small, we get a linear small-signal model, so that we can easily obtain the transfer function to design a controller for the circuit. But we usually use these transfer functions to observe the stability or dynamic performance of the circuit **under large signal disturbances** such as input voltage mutations and load mutations. **It seems that this contradict the assumption that the perturbations are small relative to the DC component when deriving the small-signal model?**

Comment: the saying goes: all models are wrong; some are useful.

Comment: That's why you have distortion.

Comment: Not all large signal disturbances constitute breaches of the assumption of linearity. It depends on the type of nonlinearity and the size of the disturbance. For example, suppose you have a ramp generator and a comparator as part of your PWM-controlled SMPS. This block may be very linear for duty cycles between, say, 15% and 85%. But the behavior may deviate sharply outside those limits. Compare this type of nonlinearity to, say, an amplifier with a strong 3rd-order distortion, which will be nonlinear everywhere except for sufficiently small disturbances.